# How to indent a region by more than one indent?

Tags: indentation, xtext, formatter

I have the following grammar:

```
Department:
  'Department:' name = ID
  'Company:' companyName = STRING
  'Persons:' persons += Person+
;

Person:
  firstName = STRING
  ':'
  surname = STRING
  ':'
  address = STRING
;
```

And I would like to have formatting like this:

```
Department: Department1
    Company: "Company1"
    Persons:
        "Person1FirstName" : "Person1LastName" : "Person1Address"
        "Person2FirstName" : "Person2LastName" : "Person2Address"
```

But when I implement the formatter code I cannot seem to be able to use indent twice since the white space formatting gets merged instead of getting concatinated.

```
class TestsFormatter extends AbstractFormatter2
{
    def dispatch void format(Department department, extension IFormattableDocument document)
    {
        department.interior[indent]
        department.regionFor.keyword("Department:").prepend[setNewLines(2)]
        department.regionFor.keyword("Department:").append[oneSpace]
        department.regionFor.keyword("Company:").prepend[newLine]
        department.regionFor.keyword("Company:").append[oneSpace]
        department.regionFor.keyword("Persons:").prepend[newLine]

        for (Person person : department.persons)
        {
            person.format
        }
    }

    def dispatch void format(Person person, extension IFormattableDocument document)
    {
        person.prepend[indent]
        person.prepend[indent]
    }
}
```

I found out that there is an example with "increaseIndentation/decreaseIndentation" in the documentation of [AbstractFormatter2](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.9/org/eclipse/xtext/formatting2/AbstractFormatter2.html). But when I try to use them, it cannot resolve them.

Comment: sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305293/how-to-define-different-indentation-levels-in-the-same-document-with-xtext-forma

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Thanks, that custom replacer did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this by using a custom replacer similar as described in [How to define different indentation levels in the same document with Xtext formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305293/how-to-define-different-indentation-levels-in-the-same-document-with-xtext-forma)