# Formatting string content xtext 2.14

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

Given a grammar (simplified version below) where I can enter arbitrary text in a section of the grammar, is it possible to format the content of the arbitrary text? I understand how to format the position of the arbitrary text in relation to the rest of the grammar, but not whether it is possible to format the content string itself?

*Sample grammar*

```
Model:
    'content' content=RT

terminal RT: // (returns ecore::EString:)
    'RT>>' -> '<<RT';
```

*Sample content*

```
content RT>>
# Some sample arbitrary text 
which I would like to format
<<RT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add custom `ITextReplacer` to the region of the string.
assuming you have a grammar like

```
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' name=STRING '!';
```

you can do something like the follow in the formatter

```
def dispatch void format(Greeting model, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
    model.prepend[newLine]
    val region  = model.regionFor.feature(MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME)
    val r = new AbstractTextReplacer(document, region) {
        override createReplacements(ITextReplacerContext it) {
            val text = region.text
            var int index = text.indexOf(SPACE);
            val offset = region.offset
            while (index >=0){
                it.addReplacement(region.textRegionAccess.rewriter.createReplacement(offset+index, SPACE.length, "\n"))
                index = text.indexOf(SPACE, index+SPACE.length())   ;
            }
            it
        }
    }
    addReplacer(r)
}
```

this will turn this model

```
Hello "A B C"!
```

into

```
Hello "A
B
C"!
```

of course you need to come up with a more sophisticated formatter logic.
see [How to define different indentation levels in the same document with Xtext formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305293/how-to-define-different-indentation-levels-in-the-same-document-with-xtext-forma) too